# Dc Dc regulator malfunction

Tags: dc-dc-converter

I am using the BD9C401EFJ chip for stepping 8.5V to 5V. The system is as stated -

1) I am supplying 8.5V from a bench power supply -> (to) BD9C401EFJ -> (output) 5V ->FT440G (another dc dc regulator) -> 3.3V (output).

2) The final output is fed to 2 KL04 freescale chips and a couple of MOSFETs and an ATMEGA32U4.

3) The whole system was working for about 3-4 months. Then suddenly, 2 BD9C401EFJ stopped working. The thing I noticed was that the o/p 5V and the ground pin was shorted. In other words the output of the BD9C401EFJ and the ground was shorted. But surprisingly there was none of the current inrush usually associated with a Vcc and GND short. The bench supply was sending like 100mAmps or so. But in the o/p of the BD9C401EFJ  there was 0V (nothing).

So, I delved into the datasheet. In the logic level diagram(internal) of the chip , shown below, I noticed the low side MOSFET (from the S-R flip flop) between the pins SW and PGND. Maybe, it is busted was my thought. I then depopulated the chip and did a connectivity test between pins 7/8 and 1. As suspected it was showing short.

How can that be so, I have not exceeded its parameters (input was just 8.5V and went a max of 12V). Also, I was supplying mostly in the range of a 100-200 mAmps.
So how is this mosfet damaged. I do not have any diode(schottky) from the supply. But, it is a bench power supply. But, I suspect that this could be one of the causes. Could anyone kindly help me out pls.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That very well could have been what happened.  This can be a problem with internal switch regulators in that you may have had a shoot-through event, a time where both of the internal mosfets were activated, and current shot straight from your VIN to PGND.  This would cause massive current flow and could damage the internal components of the IC.  I don't see any mention of shoot-through event protection on the datasheet.

If you are running this all the time, then this may not be the best regulator for your application, I note a piece in regards to the Over-current protection:

> However, the IC should
>   not be used in applications characterized by continuous
>   operation

Comment: sir.  a thought. The statement u mentioned is more like -
"The IC should not be used in applications where the over current protection circuit will be
activated continuously.". I have kept the bench power supply in a limiting factor of abt 1.5Amps. So how is this trigerred. Ofcourse there is no doubt that the chip MOSFET (low side) keeps getting blown off. Even strange that it worked for a couple of months and then 2 pop off in 10 minutes.

Comment: also, i do not have a diode(schottky) to prevent transients. Its because I am powering it up via a bench power supply. Is than an issue !!!!

Comment: That very well could be what they meant considering its context.